# Documenting default value of magic properties

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc, dynamic-properties

> @property shows a "magic" property variable that is found inside the class.

Any suggestion for documentation of default value of magic properties? Hopefully in a way that PhpStorm understands.

Comment: Does PHPDoc provides such functionality? Nope. Same will be for PhpStorm (that reads/understands PHPDoc)

Comment: What's the exact use case in which PhpStorm needs to know the value of a property and not just its type? Because if you're only expecting to see it in the tooltip a regular textual explanation in the comment should do.